# Is it possible to listen for an event when a filter has completed?

Tags: actionscript-3

For instance, I'm applying filters to large bitmaps. At the moment it works on a Timer, but I'd like to wait until any processing's been completed and progress to the next iteration at that point, instead of forcing it when the next tick comes around.

Pretty sure this can't be done. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

`BitmapFilter`, the [super class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filters/BitmapFilter.html) of all filters, doesn't extend from `EventDispatcher` class nor does it implement `IEventDispatcher` interface. So no, filters don't dispatch events.

Answer (score 0):

Filters are called synchronously so there's no event to wait for, it's done once the next line of code is executed.

Comment: with the exception of calling out to pixel bender, but that's a bit different

Answer (score 0):

grapefrukt: well, usually, but applying a glow or blur to a massive bitmap with transparent bits can take ages. So while it's still technically synchronous, I wanted to wait till it was done before doing the next bit.

Didn't think it could be done, but thought it was worth a shot! Cheers.